# Is the Key Bindings delay unavoidable in Java when pressing different directional keys quickly?

Tags: java, 2d, events

I've read just about every tutorial I can on why to use Key Bindings instead of implementing the KeyListener interface, including all the examples that show using a field to track the key event because of the repeating delay when holding down the same key. No matter what I do though I simply can't get past a keyboard delay when alternating quickly between directions (i.e. - 'W','D','S','A'). I've read some comments that state this is very dependent on your keyboard OS settings, and in some cases is just unavoidable. Some of the registry editing suggestions for keyboard speed seem to indicate there is some truth in that. Is there a posted solution somewhere that guarantees a "hardware independent" Java solution for handling quick key presses without delay?

Answer (score 2):

You might consider using JInput, you won't suffer the same problem.

Comment: Where is it documented that I won't suffer the same problem with JInput? I can't find any good examples for easily detecting key presses with this API. It looks to be built primarily for emulating game controllers, which is not what I want.

Comment: JInput is the equivalent of DirectInput on Windows platforms. That's the best you can use for getting the states of any of your devices. It contains some examples as well, check its source code and you will find it.

Comment: LMGTFY: http://www.java-gaming.org/index.php?topic=16866.0

Comment: How about you take the time to read your own link. If it contains examples of handling keyboard input then you should point me at those because I'm not seeing it. If the only way I can use the library for keyboard input is by grokking source code then it's not something I'm interested in using.

Comment: I took a look at my link, I listened to you. I see how to launch a program which displays the state of the devices connected to the computer. That should be enough for you to know where to look at in the source code in order to find the example classes, and to know how to implement what you need.

Maybe you need me to write it for you?

Comment: Which still does not answer my original question, does not address the issue that there is no sample documentation for keyboard input for the API you recommend, and demonstrates your total lack of willingness to help beyond posting a one sentence answer. I've had great success with this stack exchange and the community has been very helpful and polite. Don't ruin it for others who make an honest attempt to be involved.

Comment: Good luck with other answers.